# Add right column menu items in Admin - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, menu, column, adminmenu

I have successfully been able to add multiple submenus items with submenu headers in a custom main menu panel within the admin menu panel as per below;

```
   <!-- Add Main Menu/NEw panel Menu -->

    <add id="My_Module::main" 
         title="My Menu" 
         module="My_Module" 
         sortOrder="1" 
         resource="My_Module::main"/>


    <!-- Sub Menu Header -->

    <add id="My_Module::header" 
         title="XAPI" 
         module="My_Module" 
         sortOrder="10"
         resource="My_Module::header" 
         parent="My_Module::core"/>

   <!-- Sub Menu Item/Link -->

    <add id="My_Module::settings" 
         title="Manage Settings" 
         module="My_Module" 
         sortOrder="10" 
         action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/settings" 
         resource="My_Module::settings" 
         parent="My_Module::header"/>

   ...
   ...
   more headers, more items etc
```

Problem is I can keep adding menu header with items **but I wish to start having some be positioned into the right hand column** as seen in the "Stores" admin menu panel etc.

Comment: Seems as though if you max out the left column, menu items get pushed to the right but the these inner menu items are not responsive design based. Still not sure how the "reports" menu for example is coded to push even to a third column even though left column isn't maxed out with menu items.